# Image Upload with CKEditor in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, ckeditor, wysiwyg, ckeditor5

I want to use CKEditor with react (redux), and upload image files. Text editor successfully works, but doesn't work image uploader. I got a error when I select image. screenshot blow.

[image: screenshot ckeditor]

And my code:

```html
<div className="App">
  <h2>Using CKEditor 5 Framework in React</h2>
  <CKEditor
    editor={ ClassicEditor }
    onInit={ editor => {
      console.log( "Editor is ready to use", editor)
    }}
    onChange={ ( event, editor ) => console.log( editor.getData() ) }
    config={ {
        plugins: [ Essentials, Paragraph, Bold, Italic, Heading, Alignment, UploadAdapter, Autoformat,
                    EasyImage, Image, ImageCaption, ImageStyle, ImageToolbar, ImageUpload, ],
                  toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', '|', 'undo', 'redo', '|',  'alignment', '|', 'imageUpload'],
        ckfinder: {
          uploadUrl: 'https://example.com/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images&responseType=json'
        },
    } }

    data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
  />
</div>
```

Second Question,

I will make POST button, and save fully html code included image url in database and image files in backend folder when I "click" POST button. But, I think Images are saved previously using `ckfinder` before clicking POST button. So, how can I handle images with `not-clicked-post-button post (canceled post)`? If someone only upload images but quit posting, useless images remain in my server repository, right?

plz reply and help me

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's your case, but you should have server-side connector that run **on your server**, https://example.com - it's not valid url.

Here's the PHP installation guide https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-php/quickstart.html#quickstart_installation_folders

Also, you should have installed CKFInder plugin

```
import CKFinder from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder/src/ckfinder';
```